# Display Date of the timestamp from the input field use only IST result should be in p tag in javascript

Tags: javascript

Display Date of the timestamp from the input field use only IST result should be in p tag (example: timestamp of 1382086394000 must have a output --> Tue Jul 29 45766 12:43:20 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

```js
function showDate(){
    //Start Your code here
      

    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Static Template</title>
   </head>
  <body>

<label for='tstamp'>TimeStamp</label><input type='text' id='in1' name='tstamp' oninput='showDate()'> <p id='result'></p> </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you're looking for solutions to homework questions, you've to show your effort, problem you're facing and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Javascript Date Function

```js
function showDate(){
    //Start Your code here
    const timestampEntered = Number(event.currentTarget.value);
    result.textContent = new Date(timestampEntered).toString();
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Static Template</title>
   </head>
  <body>

<label for='tstamp'>TimeStamp</label><input type='text' id='in1' name='tstamp' oninput='showDate()'> <p id='result'></p> </body>
</html>
```